# Does kubernetes kubectl run with image creates deployment yaml file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to use Minikube and Docker to understand the concepts of Kubernetes architecture.

I created a spring boot application with Dockerfile, created tag and pushed to Dockerhub.

In order to deploy the image in K8s cluster, i issued the below command,

```
# deployed the image
$ kubectl run <deployment-name> --image=<username/imagename>:<version> --port=<port the app runs>

# exposed the port as nodeport
$ kubectl expose deployment <deployment-name> --type=NodePort
```

Everything worked and i am able to see the 1 pods running `kubectl get pods`

The Docker image i pushed to Dockerhub didn't had any deployment YAML file.

Below command produced an yaml output

**Does `kubectl` command creates deployment Yaml file out of the box?**

```
 $ kubectl get deployments --output yaml
```

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    annotations:
      deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    creationTimestamp: "2019-12-24T14:59:14Z"
    generation: 1
    labels:
      run: hello-service
    name: hello-service
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "76195"
    selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/hello-service
    uid: 90950172-1c0b-4b9f-a339-b47569366f4e
  spec:
    progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
    replicas: 1
    revisionHistoryLimit: 10
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        run: hello-service
    strategy:
      rollingUpdate:
        maxSurge: 25%
        maxUnavailable: 25%
      type: RollingUpdate
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          run: hello-service
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: thirumurthi/hello-service:0.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: hello-service
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8800
            protocol: TCP
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
        restartPolicy: Always
        schedulerName: default-scheduler
        securityContext: {}
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  status:
    availableReplicas: 1
    conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: "2019-12-24T14:59:19Z"
      lastUpdateTime: "2019-12-24T14:59:19Z"
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      status: "True"
      type: Available
    - lastTransitionTime: "2019-12-24T14:59:14Z"
      lastUpdateTime: "2019-12-24T14:59:19Z"
      message: ReplicaSet "hello-service-75d67cc857" has successfully progressed.
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      status: "True"
      type: Progressing
    observedGeneration: 1
    readyReplicas: 1
    replicas: 1
    updatedReplicas: 1
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to understand whats going on under the hood when you create kubernetes resources using **imperative commands** (versus **declarative approach** by writing and applying yaml definition files) is to run a simple example with 2 additional flags:

```
--dry-run
```

and

```
--output yaml
```

Names of these flags are rather self-explanatory so I think there is no further need for comment explaining what they do. You can simply try out the below examples and you'll see the effect:

```
kubectl run nginx-example --image=nginx:latest --port=80 --dry-run --output yaml
```

As you can see it produces the appropriate yaml manifest without applying it and creating actual deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx-example
  name: nginx-example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx-example
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: nginx-example
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:latest
        name: nginx-example
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Same with `expose` command:

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx-example --type=NodePort --dry-run --output yaml
```

produces the following output:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx-example
  name: nginx-example
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: nginx-example
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

And now the coolest part. You can use simple output redirection:

```
kubectl run nginx-example --image=nginx:latest --port=80 --dry-run --output yaml > nginx-example-deployment.yaml

kubectl expose deployment nginx-example --type=NodePort --dry-run --output yaml > nginx-example-nodeport-service.yaml
```

to save generated `Deployment` and `NodePort Service` definitions so you can further modify them if needed and apply using either `kubectl apply -f filename.yaml` or `kubectl create -f filename.yaml`.

Btw. `kubectl run` and `kubectl expose` are generator-based commands and as you may have noticed when creating your deployment (as you probably got the message: `kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1beta1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl create instead.`) they use `--generator` flag. If you don't specify it explicitly it gets the default value which for `kubectl run` is `--generator=deployment/apps.v1beta1` so by default it creates a `Deployment`. But you can modify it by providing `--generator=run-pod/v1 nginx-example` and instead of `Deployment` it will create a single `Pod`. When we go back to our previous example it may look like this:

```
kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 nginx-example --image=nginx:latest --port=80 --dry-run --output yaml
```

I hope this answered your question and clarified a bit the mechanism of creating kubernetes resources using **imperative commands**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `kubectl run` creates a deployment. If you look at the label field, you can see `run: hello-service`. This label is used later in the selector.